# how to enable partitioning option true after installing the Oracle?

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I have installed oracle 10G XE but in the time of installation i may have not enabled the partion option.now when i am running the command

```
select * from v$option where parameter = 'Partitioning'; its showing false ..
```

when i tried to run this script

```
   CREATE TABLE products
 (partno NUMBER,
  description VARCHAR2 (60))
PARTITION BY HASH (partno)
PARTITIONS 4
STORE IN (tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4);
```

it shows that

```
ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Partitioning
```

i have important tables there if i delete the database then i will have to face problem.

can i enable portioning option after installing??or i have to re install the oracle??please help.

Comment: As far as I know, Partitioning Tables is not available in XE edition. You'll need to upgrade to SE or EE.

Comment: ok then i have a big problem ..nyway thanks for the answer

Comment: Partition will not support in SE too.. You need to have EE edition to use it. http://www.oracle.com/database/product_editions.html

Comment: The limit of XE edition is max. 4 GB of user data. Itshould be possible to manage it without partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1983569) . Just launch Oracle Universal Installer (OUI) from folder where it installed and install Partitioning component for your database.